# Power BI - How to implement a dual filter in Power BI that influences visualizations based on distinct article count

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I'm new to Power BI and in the visual below I'm trying to implement two filters, but only managed to get the "Price Point Range" working.

[image]

This is the measure behind the visual:

```
Article_ID_Distinct_Price_Point = 

VAR _min_price_point = MINX(ALLSELECTED(ecommerce),ecommerce[price_eur])
VAR _max_price_point = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(ecommerce),ecommerce[price_eur])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(ecommerce[retailer_group_article]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(ecommerce[price_eur]), 
        ecommerce[price_eur] >= _min_price_point && 
        ecommerce[price_eur] <= _max_price_point 
         )
    )
```

But I need a second slicer "Distinct Articles Range" impacting the visual. This slicer must filters the price range bins by the number of distinct articles. So, for instance, if I input 0-100 in the slicer values, only the €0-€10 band should appear.

I have tried multiple solutions but the slicer never seems to work properly. I've tried creating a 3 level table where I calculate the number of distinct values per price band, but the output was not correct, am I missing something?

[image]

The code I've used to create the table:

```
BandArticleCount = 
SUMMARIZE(
    ecommerce, 
    PriceBands[Band 10], 
    PriceBands[Sort Band 10.Column1],
    "ArticleCount", DISTINCTCOUNT(ecommerce[retailer_group_article])
)
```

At the moment if I select 0-100 on the slicer it just gives me a blank visual.

Is it possible to get both slicers working at the same time?